# add relative path - incorrect

Tags: html, image, relative-path, src, silverstripe

I have the directory structure that is shown in the image.

If i have this code in `HomePage.ss`

```
<img src="../../images/sprites.jpg" />
```

Why this relative path is incorrect? `Failed to load the given url.`

[image]

Comment: Are you loading `HomePage.ss` directly or are you including it somewhere else?

Comment: @jon Well, if i understand the logic of silverstripe correctly, Page.ss will call HomePage.ss. From here http://doc.silverstripe.org//src/framework_3.0/docs/en/tutorials/_images/tutorial1_subtemplates-diagram.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to know about SilverStripe is that it reads your templates, and outputs them.
So if you have the url `mysite.com/home` then it will look like the file is located inside the folder `/home`, if your url is `mysite.com/page/subpage` it will appear as if the folder was `/page/subpage`

this means you can **NOT** use relative paths like "../images/sprites.jpg" in templates (you can use those in css though).

as @Mark has already mentioned in a comment, the way to go is using `$ThemeDir`m which will output the path to the theme folder, so your image should look like this: `<img src="$ThemeDir/images/sprites.jpg" />`

Answer (score 2):

Silverstripe uses a  tag so all relative urls are relative to the root url not the current pages url.

The accepted answer of  is the correct way to link to an image in the theme

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation from Silverstripe, you can acces your images with a framework URL:

```
<img src="$ThemeDir/images/sprites.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: man i don't know exactly why, but this will work `<img src="themes/simple/images/sprites.jpg">`

Comment: are you in a framework environment? Then the framework will sort this out for you, so you theme url is provided by your framework.

Comment: yes, i am using the framework of silverstripe. well, this is helpful now that i know.

Comment: is it not in the documentation? theme URL?

Comment: i think in this page : http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/theme-development it is documented how to acces images

Comment: yes, you are correct `<img src="$ThemeDir/images/sprites.jpg" />` is the correct way. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the path load the image from URL putting the correct url...

example:

img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/themes/simple/images/img/sprite.jpg"

right, click and see the image location from browser, and copy the correct url.

Comment: I want to avoid this, obviously.

Comment: please, take a look this here   ../../simple/images/img/sprite.jpg

Comment: the image is inside the images folder. not img folder.

Answer (score -1):

```
img src="../../../images/sprites.jpg"

img src="../../../images/**img**/sprites.jpg"
```